# Increase File upload for expression engine

Tags: solspace-freeform

Site is on a dedicated server, i want to be able to increase the max upload file size.

.zips of around 5mb are fine however i want in excess of 50mb to be uploaded. At the moment i get the following error:

```
This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an EE question. You would have to consult your host about increasing the max file upload size, see this old post for more information:

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/151764/

Comment: I thankyou for the reply, i have upped memory_limit, max_execution_time, max_input_time, post_max_size and upload_max_filesize. However although the file now upload fine and goes into the correct folder and free form also notifys me.... for some reason i get a weird error in relation to SMTP etc and the form does not return to the thanks page. any idea what this could be? I refreshed the page and expression engine gave me this error Missing required valid POST variable - params_id

Comment: I'd have to see your template code although I did answer your initial question correctly :) For the sake of the community I'd post your entire template and error in a new question so that it's easier for others to find if they run into the same issue.

Comment: Thankyou. I can't vote up your answer though I don't have enough rep. Thanks for making me aware that it was not an expression engine problem but a server related issue.... It's all sorted now..

Comment: No worries. Glad to help!